# Swift UITableView subview appears but controller never called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I'm building a simple swift iOS app with a TableView that only takes up part of the screen. I have a `FirstViewController` that handles a long of info on the page and is the default landing page (it works as expected). A section of the page is a table view which I have created a new controller for `BucketViewController.swift`. That file looks like:

```
import UIKit

class BucketViewController: UITableViewController {

    var buckets = [String]()
    var newBucket: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print("INSIDE BUCKET")
        super.viewDidLoad()

        buckets = ["A", "B", "C"]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return buckets.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("TABLEVIEW")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("bucketCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel!.text = buckets[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }   
}
```

In the storyboard, there is a Table View with the class `bucketViewController`. There is a prototype cell called `bucketCell` with a `textLabel`.

When I run the app the tableView appears, but it is blank. `INSIDE BUCKET` is never printed which makes me think the controller is never called. Any idea why this is?

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: "In storyboard has a Table View with the class bucketViewController"    --  the controller in storyboard should be a TableViewController and the class of it should be  bucketViewController

Comment: @Subbu [updated] In the storyboard, there is a Table View with the class `bucketViewController`